Не работает логин через Google (Google Sign In + Firebase) // Unity
При выборе аккаунта ничего не происходит. Не понимаю, на что он жалуется!?
Скрипт авторизации:
using UnityEngine;
using Google;
using Firebase.Auth;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Firebase.Extensions;

namespace Bonfire
{
    public class GoogleAuth : OnClickButton_Base
    {
        [Header("Google API")]
        [SerializeField] private string googleWebAPI;
        [SerializeField] private TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI debug;

        private GoogleSignInConfiguration _config;

        private Firebase.DependencyStatus _dependencyStatus;
        private FirebaseAuth _auth;
        private FirebaseUser _user;

        private void Awake()
        {
            _config = new GoogleSignInConfiguration
            {
                WebClientId = googleWebAPI,
                RequestIdToken = true
            };
        }

        protected override void Start()
        {
            base.Start();

            _auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        }

        protected override void AfterClick()
        {
            OnClickGoogleSingIn();
        }

        private void OnClickGoogleSingIn()
        {
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration = _config;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
            GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestEmail = true;

            GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(OnGoogleAuthFinished);
        }

        private void OnGoogleAuthFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task)
        {
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Fault 1");
                debug.text = "Fault 1" + task.Exception.ToString();
            }
            else if(task.IsCanceled)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Is Cancel 1");
            }
            else
            {
                Credential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.GetCredential(task.Result.IdToken, null);

                _auth.SignInWithCredentialAsync(credential).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
                {
                    if(task.IsCanceled)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("Is Cancel 2");
                        return;
                    }
                    if(task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("Fault 2: ");
                        debug.text = "Fault 2" + task.Exception.ToString();
                        return;
                    }
                    if(task.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        _user = _auth.CurrentUser;
                        debug.text = "Complete" + _user.DisplayName;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}


